# Cannot Delete _fbp Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, facebook-pixel

I have a button to give users the option to accept cookies, and another for them to revoke the cookies.

I am using the Cookie Notice for GDPR plugin by dFactory and Google Analytics Dashboard Plugin for WordPress by MonsterInsights.
I am using Facebook Pixel via a Google Tag Manager script on my website.

When the revoke button is clicked I revoke the cookies and reload the page. All my cookies delete successfully, but when I try to revoke the `_fbp` cookie it persists.

```
Name: _fbp
Value: fb.1.1562101432060.130183292
Domain: .upperroombooks.com
Path: / 
Expires/Max-Age: 2019-09-30T21:03:52.000Z
Size: 32
HTTP:
Secure:
SameSite:
```

I am using the following code to attempt to delete the cookie:

```
document.cookie = '_fbp' + '=; Path=/; Domain=.upperroom.org; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

(Again, this method works for the other cookies.)

Funny enough, when I enter this code in the dev tools console it deletes the cookie as expected.

Comment: Do you got the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the `_fbp` cookie is:

```
Domain: .upperroombooks.com
```

When you're deleting the cookie, the domain you're trying to use is:

```
Domain= .upperroom.org
```

There may be an invalid domain warning in your console alluding to this.

If you correctly set (or remove) the Domain, it should work without issue.

I don't expect this will help the OP over 2 years on but it might help someone.